# ^M appearing in minibuffer

Tags: minibuffer, line-endings

when I invoke some function that requires to select an option from the minibuffer, there is often a first option tagged with `[^M]`

what does it mean? How to select it?

Comment: `^M` is a a control character (`carriage return`) obtained with `C-m`. But I don't know of any instance where that is required to select an option from the minibuffer. Can you edit your question and provide an example where that arises?

Comment: for example when I edit latex document with Auctex package, and I want to insert a reference using `C- [`, I am sent into minibuffer with first option being `^M`. Maybe, from what you say, I need to press RET into minibuffer. I need to test this.

Comment: The first option I get is `Regex { && Regex...}: [cite]: `. I type a pattern, it highlights the matches in the bibtex file and allows me to use `n` and `p` to move from entry to entry and select an entry by pressing RET. There is no explicit `^M` anywhere that I can see.